# Recomended way to create a matrix containing strings in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I need to write a programm that collects different datasets and unites them. For this I have to read in a comma seperated matrix: In this case each row represents an instance (in this case proteins), each column represents an attribute of the instances. If an instance has an attribute, it is represented by a 1, otherwise 0. The matrix looks like the example given below, but much larger, with 35000 instances and hundreds of attributes.

```
Proteins,Attribute 1,Attribute 2,Attribute 3,Attribute 4
Protein 1,1,1,1,0
Protein 2,0,1,0,1
Protein 3,1,0,0,0
Protein 4,1,1,1,0
Protein 5,0,0,0,0
Protein 6,1,1,1,1
```

I need a way to store the matrix before writing into a new file with other information about the instances. I thought of using numpy arrays, since i would like to be able to select and check single columns. I tried to use numpy.empty to create the array of the given size, but it seems that you have to preselect the lengh of the strings and cannot change them afterwards.

Is there a better way to deal with such data? I also thought of dictionarys of lists but then iI cannot select single columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.loadtxt`, for example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',',usecols=(1,2,3,4),
               skiprows=1, dtype=float)
```

Which will result in something like:

```
#array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
#       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Or, using `structured arrays` (`np.recarray'):

```
a = np.loadtxt('stack.txt', delimiter=',',usecols=(1,2,3,4),
        skiprows=1, dtype=[('Attribute 1', float),
                           ('Attribute 2', float),
                           ('Attribute 3', float),
                           ('Attribute 4', float)])
```

from where you can get each field like:

```
a['Attribute 1']
#array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.])
```

Comment: reading about **loadtxt** I found out that there is also **numpy.genfromtxt** for the case of missing data in a matrix. (Not the case for me right now, but maybe someone will find this information useful?)

Comment: yes, you are right! I've tried `genfromtxt` for your case too, and their use for this case would be in the same way, with the same parameters...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

> pandas is an open source, BSD-licensed library providing high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools for the Python programming language.

Comment: I will try np.loadtxt this time, but pandas seems to be great thing for me in the long run. I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `genfromtxt` instead:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', dtype=None)
```

This will create a [structured array (aka record array)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) of your table.